# xpath extract text that is wrapped in href

Tags: python, html, xpath

I am new to using XPath and was confused about how to retrieve text that is wrapped in href (where I do not need href info.).

URL I am using:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Major_League_Soccer_season

HTML looks like below

[image]

Where I want to extract text "Gonzalo Pineda" and the code I have written is this

```
import requests
from lxml import HTML

t = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Major_League_Soccer_season")

dom_tree = html.fromstring(t.content)
coach = updated_dom_tree.xpath('//table[contains(@class, "wikitable")][2]//tbody/tr/td[2]/text()')
```

Where this is second table from a Wikipedia page so that's why I wrote //table[contains(@class, "wikitable")][2].

Then I wrote //tbody/tr/td[2]/text() just following the HTML structure. However, the outcome of the code returns " " (empty string with \n") without actual text info.

I tried to change the code to a[contains(@href, "wiki")] after searching through the stack overflow but I was getting an output of an empty list ([]).

I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this!

Edit:
I can't copy-paste HTML because I just got that from inspect tool (F12).

The HTML line can be found in "Personnel and sponsorships" table second column. Thank you!

Comment: Can you edit the question, add the code you used (including the url), remove the image and replace it with actual html?

Comment: @JackFleeting Thank you for the comment. I just added the URL to Wikipedia but I couldn't post the actual HTML because I just snapshot from chrome's inspect tool. Sorry about that.

Comment: pls include your import statments as that will be easy to understand what are modules you are importing., for example, `html` and also how `updated_dom_tree` is getting built.

Comment: @simpleApp I added the imports. The lines I added are entire code and it should crawl the names of coaches from the Wikipedia table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you are looking for is

```
dom_tree.xpath('(//table[contains(@class, "wikitable")]//span[@class="flagicon"])[1]//following-sibling::span//a/text()')[0]
```

Output should be

```
'Gonzalo Pineda'
```

EDIT:

To get the name of all head coaches, try:

```
for coach in dom_tree.xpath('(//table[contains(@class, "wikitable")])[2]//tbody//td[2]'):
    print(coach.xpath('.//a/text()')[0])
```

Another way to do it - using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
tab = dom_tree.xpath('(//table[contains(@class, "wikitable")])[2]')[0]
pd.read_html(HTML.tostring(tab))[0].loc[:, 'Head coach']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. The output that I am looking for is list of all head coaches so ['Gonzalo Pineda', 'Josh Wolff' ... ]. I tried to change the code a little bit by excluding [0] at the end but it did not achieve what i wanted..

Answer (score 0):

this is the approach you can take the extract the table. extra import pandas just to see how the table data is coming along.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import pandas as pd # to data storage, using pandas

t = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Major_League_Soccer_season")
dom_tree = html.fromstring(t.content)
#coach = updated_dom_tree.xpath('//table[contains(@class, "wikitable")][2]//tbody/tr/td[2]/text()')
table_data=[]
table_header=[]
table=dom_tree.xpath("//table")[2]
for e_h in table.findall(".//tr")[0]:
    table_header.append(e_h.text_content().strip())
table_data={0:[],1:[],2:[],3:[],4:[]}
for e_tr in table.findall(".//tr")[1:]:
    col_no=0
    for e_td in e_tr.findall(".//td"):
        if e_td.text_content().strip():
            table_data[col_no].append(e_td.text_content().strip())
        else:
            table_data[col_no].append('N/A') # handle spaces, 
        if e_td.get('colspan') == '2': ## handle example team Colorado Rapids, where same td spans
            col_no+=1
            table_data[col_no].append('N/A')
        else:
            col_no+=1
for i in range(0,5):
    table_data[table_header[i]] = table_data.pop(i)
df=pd.DataFrame(table_data)
```

if just want `Head Coach` column, then `table_data['Head coach']` will give those.

output:
[image]